# oracle enterprise manager agent unreachable (windows)

Tags: windows-7, oracle, oracle-11g

Since yesterday, the oracle enterprise manager tool on my windows 7 machine is saying that the agent is unreachable. I didn't do anything unusual before this appeared, if I remember correctly I only had some intensive packages running I had to abort after some hours. User or instance configuration works, so my first question would be which feature is missing now? It seems that some of the information usually being shown on the frontpage is missing, but the performance tools on the second tab still seem to work.

I tried restarting the machine, restarting the database, restarting the oracle services. Nothing helped. I was looking for help on google, and only found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/313945/oracle-enterprise-manager-showing-agent-unreachable-negative-disk-space), since most users seem to have similar problems only using unix operating systems. That link at least helped me to find the emctl tool. While trying it out, it tells me that ORACLE_UNQNAME is not defined. Google told me that this variable is supposed to contain the database instance name, which in my case is "ORCL". I can confirm this value since a tool like plsql developer uses it to connect to the database - successfully. So I tried to set this value, both using the windows control panel and the SET command in the windows command prompt. It still didn't work, it was still telling me that the variable is not defined. After another reboot, it now tells me this:

```
EM Configuration issue. c:\app\xx.xx\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1/NB16.xx-xx.intern_ORCL not found.
```

I don't understand this. Most of the Enterprise Manager frontend is still working, as is the database itself.

I would appreciate any help. Even if don't need the missing features supplied by the agent right now, I will need to work with oracle for some several years, so I need to understand what has gone wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the exact solution to it, but I yesterday found out that the partition with the tablespaces was almost full (about 1 gb remaining), so I deleted some of my unused tablespaces.
This morning, I checked the enterprise manager again, and suddenly, the agent is working again.